# VBA For Next stops working after some iterations. Need Do loop, but not skilled enough to change

Tags: excel, vba, loops

The below macro runs fine until a certain number of iterations. Then the pop up messages work, but the upload to change the sharepoint list fields does nothing. I think the For loop needs to be changed to a Do loop, but I don't know how to make that change (this was an inherited file and I'm not proficient with VBA). Can someone show me what, exactly, to change so this macro doesn't stop working after ~500 iterations?

```
    Sub Upload_SharePoint()
    
    'Define Variables
    Dim ListName As String
    Dim SharepointUrl As String
    Dim ValueVar As String
    Dim FieldNameVar As String
    Dim objXMLHTTP As Object
    Dim strListNameOrGuid As String
    Dim strBatchXml As String
    Dim strSoapBody As String
    Dim CurrentWB As Workbook
    Dim UploadWS As Worksheet
    Dim UploadRow As Long
    Dim UploadCol As Long
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim errChar As Boolean
    Dim Result As String
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Application.StatusBar = "Uploading Changes to SharePoint List..."
    
    'Prompt User to ensure they want to upload changes
    Answer = MsgBox("Are you certain that you want to proceed? Clicking Yes will overwrite all list details with the information on the Upload worksheet in this file.", vbYesNo, "Proceed?")
    
    If Answer = vbYes Then
    
        'Turn off Events
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        'Set workbook and worksheet variables
        Set CurrentWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        Set UploadWS = CurrentWB.Worksheets("Upload")
        
        'Finds last row and column in Upload worksheet
        UploadWS.Activate
        UploadRow = UploadWS.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        UploadCol = UploadWS.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column
        
        'Searches for invalid characters and throws error if any are found. Replaces ampersands with XML readable format.
        errChar = False
        For Each cell In UploadWS.Range("A2", Cells(UploadRow, UploadCol)).Cells
            If InStr(cell.Value, ">") > 0 Then
                errChar = True
                GoTo InvalidChar
            End If
            If InStr(cell.Value, "<") > 0 Then
                errChar = True
                GoTo InvalidChar
            End If
            If InStr(cell.Value, "&") > 0 Then
                Result = Replace(cell.Value, "&", "&amp;")
                cell.Value = Result
            End If
        Next cell
        
        'Define SharePoint URL and SharePoint List name
        ListName = "Project List"
        SharepointUrl = "Proprietary"  'for a subsite it would be: http://example/exampleSubsite/
        
        'Start of XML string with changes to be uploaded
        strBatchXml = "<Batch OnError='Continue'>"
        
        'Iterate through rows on Upload worksheet and write changes to Contracts Database SharePoint List
        For x = 2 To UploadRow
            strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "<Method ID='3' Cmd='Update'><Field Name='ID'>" + CStr(UploadWS.Cells(x, 1).Value) + "</Field>"
            For y = 2 To UploadCol
                If Not IsEmpty(UploadWS.Cells(1, y)) Then
                    If UploadWS.Cells(1, y).Value = "Project Name" Then
                        strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "<Field Name='Title'>" + CStr(UploadWS.Cells(x, y).Value) + "</Field>"
                    ElseIf UploadWS.Cells(1, y).Value = "Supplier Name" Then
                        strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "<Field Name='SupplierName'>" + CStr(UploadWS.Cells(x, y).Value) + "</Field>"
                    ElseIf UploadWS.Cells(1, y).Value = "Annual Spend" Then
                        strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "<Field Name='AnnualSpend'>" + CStr(UploadWS.Cells(x, y).Value) + "</Field>"
                    ElseIf UploadWS.Cells(1, y).Value = "Stage" Then
                        strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "<Field Name='Stage'>" + CStr(UploadWS.Cells(x, y).Value) + "</Field>"
                    ElseIf UploadWS.Cells(1, y).Value = "Expiration Date" Then
                        strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "<Field Name='ExpirationDate0'>" + Format(UploadWS.Cells(x, y).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") + "</Field>"
                    ElseIf UploadWS.Cells(1, y).Value = "Number of Parts" Then
                        strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "<Field Name='NumberOfParts'>" + CStr(UploadWS.Cells(x, y).Value) + "</Field>"
                    ElseIf UploadWS.Cells(1, y).Value = "Number of Documents" Then
                        strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "<Field Name='NumberOfDocuments'>" + CStr(UploadWS.Cells(x, y).Value) + "</Field>"
                    ElseIf UploadWS.Cells(1, y).Value = "Contracts Representative" Then
                        strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "<Field Name='ContractsRepresentative'>" + CStr(UploadWS.Cells(x, y).Value) + "</Field>"
                    ElseIf UploadWS.Cells(1, y).Value = "Tech Data" Then
                        strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "<Field Name='Tech_x0020_Data'>" + CStr(UploadWS.Cells(x, y).Value) + "</Field>"
                    ElseIf UploadWS.Cells(1, y).Value = "Priority" Then
                        strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "<Field Name='Priority0'>" + CStr(UploadWS.Cells(x, y).Value) + "</Field>"
                    End If
                End If
            Next y
            strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "</Method>"
        Next x
        
        'End of XML string with changes to be uploaded
        strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "</Batch>"
        Debug.Print strBatchXml
        
        'Writes changes contained in XML to SharePoint list
        Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        strListNameOrGuid = ListName
        objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", SharepointUrl + "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx", False
        objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""UTF-8"""
        objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems"
        strSoapBody = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " _
         & "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' " _
         & "xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><UpdateListItems " _
         & "xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>" & strListNameOrGuid _
         & "</listName><updates>" & strBatchXml & "</updates></UpdateListItems></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
        objXMLHTTP.send strSoapBody
        
        'Error handling for XML
        If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
            Debug.Print "Error!"
        End If
        
        'Cleanup
        Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
                
        'Turn on Events
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.StatusBar = False
        
        'Message Box on Complete
        MsgBox ("Changes uploaded to Database.")
        UploadWS.Activate
        
    Else
        GoTo ExitVBA
        
    End If
    
    'Turn on Events
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    
    InvalidChar:
    If errChar = True Then
        Message = MsgBox("Invalid character found. Cell values cannot contain angle brackets: < or >", vbCritical, "Invalid Character")
    End If
    
    'Adds back in normal ampersands
    For Each cell In UploadWS.Range("A2", Cells(UploadRow, UploadCol)).Cells
        If InStr(cell.Value, "&amp;") > 0 Then
            Result = Replace(cell.Value, "&amp;", "&")
            cell.Value = Result
        End If
    Next cell
    
    'Turn on Events
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    
    ExitVBA:
    
    'Turn on Events
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    
    End Sub`enter code here`
```

Comment: It could be that the value of `UploadRow` is not what you want it to be. To check it, you could put `MsgBox("UploadRow = " & UploadRow)` after the line that sets its value and see if it what you need it to be or if it is something else.

Comment: But wouldn't that break the macro regardless of number of iterations run?

Comment: No, it'll just tell you how many iterations it "thinks" it should be doing. If it is only about 500 when it should be more then you need to investigate why it was set too low. If it shows the expected value then you need to look at the value of `strBatchXml` before it is sent (it might be easiest to write it to a file to view instead of looking at the output of the `Debug.Print`). If that string is correct then you need to find out if the Sharepoint asmx page will accept that much data in one go.

Comment: I think you're on to something with the Sharepoint asmx page limitation. the macro works again every day, like it's been reset, but not after restarting my PC. Sounds like the sharepoint site resetting the daily limits at midnight. Not sure how to change those limits though...

Comment: You have `If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then Debug.Print "Error!"` but a status of 200 typically means success ("OK")   I'd add a little more logic around the return value from the call to the API.

Comment: FYI seems there's a limit of 160 items when you call that method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb249818(v=office.14)#:~:text=The%20number%20of%20list%20items%20that%20you%20can%20modify%20through%20the%20UpdateListItems(String%2C%20XmlNode)%20method%20in%20a%20single%20batch%20is%20limited%20to%20160.  You should batch your updates into smaller sets of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can batch up your updates so you don't overshoot the 160-item limit on the API method.

Tested on a simple list (and refactored quite a bit...)

```vb
Sub Upload_SharePoint()
    
    'define constants
    Const BATCH_SIZE As Long = 50
    Const LIST_NAME As String = "TestList33"
    Const LIST_URL As String = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Site1/"  
    
    'Define Variables
    Dim strBatchXml As String, CurrentWB As Workbook, UploadWS As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, Answer, numRecs As Long
    Dim Result As String, data As Variant, nm As String, v, hdr, cLast As Range
    
    Application.StatusBar = "Uploading Changes to SharePoint List..."
    
    'Prompt User to ensure they want to upload changes
    Answer = MsgBox("Are you certain that you want to proceed? " & vbLf & vbLf & _
             "Clicking Yes will overwrite all list details with the information" & vbLf & _
             " on the Upload worksheet in this file.", vbYesNo, "Proceed?")
    
    If Answer <> vbYes Then Exit Sub 'nothing to do here
    
    Set UploadWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Upload")
    Set cLast = LastCell(UploadWS)        'find last cell on sheet with content
    If cLast Is Nothing Then Exit Sub     'no content on sheet
    data = UploadWS.Range("A1", cLast)    'load data to array
    
    strBatchXml = "<Batch OnError='Continue'>" 'Start of XML string with changes to be uploaded
    
    For x = 2 To UBound(data, 1)       'loop over array rows
        numRecs = numRecs + 1          'increment record count
        strBatchXml = strBatchXml & "<Method ID='3' Cmd='Update'>" & _
                                    "<Field Name='ID'>" & data(x, 1) & "</Field>"
        For y = 2 To UBound(data, 2)   'loop over array columns
            nm = ""                    'reset attribute value
            v = data(x, y)             'data value
            hdr = data(1, y)           'column header
            If Len(hdr) > 0 Then       'if there's a header
                Select Case hdr        'map column header to XML "Name" attribute value
                    Case "Title": nm = "Title"
                    Case "Project Name": nm = "Title"
                    Case "Supplier Name": nm = "SupplierName"
                    Case "Annual Spend": nm = "AnnualSpend"
                    Case "Stage": nm = "Stage"
                    Case "Expiration Date"
                        nm = "ExpirationDate0"
                        v = Format(v, "yyyy-mm-dd")
                    Case "Number of Parts": nm = "NumberOfParts"
                    Case "Number of Documents": nm = "NumberOfDocuments"
                    Case "Contracts Representative": nm = "ContractsRepresentative"
                    Case "Tech Data": nm = "Tech_x0020_Data"
                    Case "Priority": nm = "Priority0"
                End Select
                
                If Len(nm) > 0 Then  'got a match on column header?
                    strBatchXml = strBatchXml & "<Field Name='" & nm & "'>" & CleanForXml(v) & "</Field>"
                End If
            
            End If 'have a column header
        Next y
        strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "</Method>"
        numRecs = numRecs + 1
        
        'need to send a batch (reached a multiple of BATCH_SIZE, or this was the last record)?
        If (numRecs Mod BATCH_SIZE = 0) Or (x = UBound(data, 1)) Then
            strBatchXml = strBatchXml + "</Batch>"
            Debug.Print "RunListUpdate=" & RunListUpdate(LIST_NAME, LIST_URL, strBatchXml)
            strBatchXml = "<Batch OnError='Continue'>"
        End If
    
    Next x         'next record
    
    MsgBox "Changes uploaded to Database"
    UploadWS.Activate
    
    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub

'escape &, <, >, ", '
Function CleanForXml(ByVal v)
    v = Replace(v, "&", "&amp;")
    v = Replace(v, """", "&quot;")
    v = Replace(v, "'", "&apos;")
    v = Replace(v, "<", "&lt;")
    CleanForXml = Replace(v, ">", "&gt;")
End Function

'Call SharePoint SOAP API to update one or more items in a named List
Function RunListUpdate(ListName As String, ListUrl As String, BatchXml As String) As Boolean
    Dim objXMLHTTP As Object, strSoapBody As String
    
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", ListUrl + "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx", False
    objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""UTF-8"""
    objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems"
    
    strSoapBody = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " _
     & "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' " _
     & "xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><UpdateListItems " _
     & "xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>" & ListName _
     & "</listName><updates>" & BatchXml & "</updates></UpdateListItems></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
    
    objXMLHTTP.Send strSoapBody
    
    Debug.Print objXMLHTTP.responseText
    RunListUpdate = (objXMLHTTP.Status = 200) 'check the return status
    If Not RunListUpdate Then
        Debug.Print "Error!", objXMLHTTP.responseText
    End If
End Function

'return the last used cell on a sheet, or Nothing if not content on sheet.
Function LastCell(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim fR As Range, fC As Range
    'Last row and column in Upload worksheet
    Set fR = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not fR Is Nothing Then
        Set fC = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Set LastCell = ws.Cells(fR.row, fC.Column)
    End If
End Function
```